# hidden all files public_html! but how?

Tags: linux, website, node.js

My host has hidden files on my node.js webserver (he did this may/june 2013) and can't remember how/what he did...

I need to ask at this point as I have been reading around centos stuff and looking into http.config file and not really seeing anything change when turning things off and on again.

the symptoms:

when you goto mysite.com all you see is index of (no files are shown) but the public_html is full of .js files, folders, an image .png **(this is good)**

when you go to mysite.com/example.png you get 404 not found **(this is bad)**

when you go to mysite.com/example.js you get 404 not found **(this is good!)**

the code in .js files can be accessed just fine by my_client_code_site.com **(this is also good!)**

any clues as to how this behaviour was achieved?

is this helpful?:

```
ServerName ${DOM}
ServerAlias www.${DOM}
DocumentRoot ${HOME}/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/${DOM}_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/${DOM}_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ ${HOME}/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory ${HOME}/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
<Directory ${HOME}/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

**UPDATE**

More info from my host:

a) only two domains running, files are visible on one domain, not on the other (so whatever rule there is, it's working not server-wide)

b) virtual host config in httpd.conf is identical for both domains (except forIP address and paths, of course)

c) I tried swapping the names of the home dirs with each other (and chown accordingly) and it still does not work (files invisible)

Where else can I look to pinpoint what it could be?

**UPDATE:** we think it has something to do with the **referer**

Comment: Possibly more appropriate on unix.se? So people can answer your question, please show appropriate config files from your httpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Apache error-log, or access-log.  I'd suggest this might be some mod_rewrite or other `.htaccess` security.

Perhaps the simplest way to proceed would be to ask the admin who made the change(s) what they did, why they did it, and how to revert.

**EDIT**: Is your webserver apache, or is it a node.js application?  You're not 100% explcit.

Comment: there is no .htaccess file(s)

Comment: webserver is centos6/apache i think. and it is running a node.js app

Comment: node.js runs as a server.  apache runs as a server.  **WHICH ONE** is returning the 404s?

Comment: apache i guess seen **as i said** "when you go to mysite.com/example.png you get 404 not found". (viewing a .png doesn't have anything to do with node)

Comment: I use a node.js server to serve a website, it will happily return HTML, JSON, and PNGS.  You're really not giving us enough information to go on so I'm afraid you're not likely to get an answer.

Comment: im doing my best im just a javascript programmer

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked DNS/NS to ensure the domain is going to the correct server? Otherwise, check the vhost configurations again and ensure the document root is correct.

EDIT: have you checked permissions of the files?

Comment: the document root is correct and its not a dns issue because everything else resolving fine

Comment: Check permissions? Incorrect permissions will create 404's

Comment: already checked them, they are not the cause

Answer (score 1):

There may be a .htaccess file in your public_html folder that is preventing access to those files.

Comment: there are no .htaccess files on the server